# WebDriver script for clicking all links except one with particular name not working

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, webdriver

I am in process of learning Selenium WebDriver 2 using Java/Junit with IntelliJ IDEA.

The sample page I am using for creating scripts is http://newtours.demoaut.com/

I am trying to create a script that will click on all the links on the page EXCEPT the "SUPPORT" link.

I've imported all the necessary libraries and

Here is the code that I tried to use but it gives an error:

```
public class AllLinksExceptSupport{

WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
String url="http://newtours.demoaut.com/";

@Before
public void loadhomepage()
{
driver.get(url);

@Test
public void allexceptregister(){
   List<WebElement> alllinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (int i =0; i<= alllinks.size()-1; i++){
    String oflinks = alllinks.get(i).getText();
    if(oflinks.equals("SUPPORT")){
      continue;
    }
     alllinks.get(i).click();
}
}
}
```

Here is the error message:

org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up.

Can you please advise on what I'm doing wrong and what needs to be changed in the code/logic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is that when you click a link, you're leaving the page.  This makes the collection of elements in your List "stale".

This is an approach that should work for you.  Of course, this assumes that all of the links have different link text.

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
String ofLinks[] = new String[allLinks.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < allLinks.size(); i++){
    if(!allLinks.get(i).getText().equals("SUPPORT")){
       ofLinks[i] = allLinks.get(i).getText();
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < allLinks.size(); i++){
    if (ofLinks[i] != null){
        driver.findElement(By.LinkText(ofLinks[i])).click();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home")).click();
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your answer. When I run the script you gave me, the console continues to give me an error:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"your destination"}.
Also, can I ask you, which line returns me back to the original page?

Comment: NoSuchElement means it can't find the element in the page.  StaleElement means that it had found the element on the page, but can no longer find it.

Comment: Thank you for your help but it still opens the page that it's supposed to skip.

Comment: I believe the corrections I've made will work for you now.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you! That worked after adding the square brackets after String ofLinks in your code so it looks like
    String ofLinks[] = new String[allLinks.size()];

Comment: Ah sorry.  I'm not completely familiar with java, I generally use c#.  I'll make that correction.